# How to change a file permission while it's already opened by another application

Tags: c#, windows, command-prompt

I am the administrator of my PC and I'm writing an application that can manage shared files permissions. My problem is when I want to set permission to a new user for accessing the shared files, the Windows throws an error that Your file or folder is opened by another user or application. Is there any solution to solving that?

Comment: File attributes and security are metadata, which is not subject to shared read, write, and delete data access. You would only get a sharing violation if your application mistakenly requested data access. We only need read-control, write-dac, and (maybe) write-owner and access-system-security access in order to read and modify file security.

Comment: You're getting a sharing violation only because your application is requesting data access. If .NET is to blame, then the answer would be to P/Invoke lower-level Windows API functions, such as [`SetNamedSecurityInfoW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-setnamedsecurityinfow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"cmd.exe /C tasklist.exe /FI " + """imagename eq explorer.exe""" + " > C:\tmptxt.txt"
```

Read List; kill higher PIDs until only one is left which is the desktop.

You can also run it before and after you process your program to check if excess processes or extra ones are being crated, if so be careful how you’re managing your FileSystemObject